# Indexing a document with content using solrj in EmbeddedSolrServer

Tags: indexing, solr, solrj, apache-tika

I want to query an `EmbeddedSolrServer` instance with a Filter query. Like we normally do in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtW2H.png) with an admin panel. But the problem here is that I want to do this programmatically with Java. I know that we can do that `query.setQuery("*:*");` , but this is not what I want if someone want to search by a specific word in content's document. I found also this `solrParams.add(CommonParams.QT, "*:*");`, But it's not working. I think that may be the problem is from parsing the PDF document, when I try to index it. So please if someone know how to index a document using `EmbeddedSolrServer` exactly the same way we index it using `post.jar` in command.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing a file is as easy as

```
EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(solrHome, defaultCoreName)
ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
req.addFile(fileToIndex, "application/octet-stream");
req.setParam("commit", "true");
req.setParam("literal.id", id);
NamedList<Object> namedList = server.request(req);
server.close();
```